# PowerPivot - how to "freeze" data?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I apologise if this has been asked before - I have searched the internet endlessly for an answer.

I have several Excel files which connect to Databases via PowerPivot - I use PowerPivot to manipulate the data before producing various PivotTables in Excel.

Every month, the source Databases are update with the latest month's data and with any existing records updated for their latest status.

I want to be able to keep Excel files for each month that I can go back and run new PivotTables if I need. However, I want to ensure that it is not possible for the user to Refresh the PowerPivot connection as otherwise the original data will be lost. Is this possible?